# Відповідник до російського вислову "Довольный как слон"

Tags: переклад, from-russian, фразеологізми

"Довольный как слон" - означає, що людина чимось дуже задоволена. Цікавить чи є в українській мові відповідник. Я спробував шукати в СУМі, а також в Інтернеті (наприклад сайт [ЗНО](https://zno.if.ua/?p=2364) та на сайті [Розум](http://www.rozum.org.ua/search)), але не зміг знайти. Поки-що на думку нічого не спадає.

Answer (score 1):

Сьогодні ввечері читав статтю "[Туристичний Ізюм: Парк п'яти картин](http://ito.vspu.net/enk/2013_2014/Osn_projekt_tehnologi_spec/Rob_stud/Punko/doc_html/Dnipropetrovsk/%D0%A2%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%96%D0%B7%D1%8E%D0%BC.htm)", де натрапив на таке речення:

> У такі дні він був **щасливий, як дитя**, оскільки йому належить працювати
>   ...

"Щасливий, як дитя" - як на мене хороший відповідник. Але не все так просто, так як я не можу знайти цього вислову в жодному із словників. Хоч прикладів в Інтернеті є багато:

Фрагмент книги "[Сонячні знаки](http://goroskop2.com.ua/sumisnosti-rak-i-ribi-linda-gudman/)":

> Одягнений у все нове, він виходив разом з сином з магазину, **щасливий,
>   як дитя**.

Повідомлення на [форумі](https://uoor.com.ua/forum/index.php?threads/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA.44908/page-440#post-459560):

> Я з внучкою на чотирьох поповзав і щасливий як дитя.

А також багато інших прикладів як з літератури, так і з інших форумів (тобто населення нашої країни такий вислів знає). Хочу запитати спільноти чи ще хтось чув про такий вислів?

Можу ще запропонувати таку заміну як "[**На сьомому небі**](http://www.rozum.org.ua/index.php?a=term&d=24&t=549)", приклад:

"Він на сьомому небі від щастя"